# What distance metric can I use for comparing image features like elongation and solidity of each image?

Tags: image-processing

What distance metric can I use for comparing image features like elongation and solidity of a contour of each image? 
Except Least Square and without using a support vector machine because i do not know at which class images belong.

Comment: Have you tried using the first two eigenvectors of the contour matrix (or its covariance matrix) as a measure for elongation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, each contour is described by a 2-element feature vector $f = [e, s]$, where $e$ is elongation and $s$ is solidity.

In that case, you might want to try the [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance), which is defined as follows:
$$d(f_1, f_2) = \sqrt{(f_2 - f_1)C^{-1}(f_2 - f_1)}$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the feature vectors that you are comparing, and $C$ is the covariance matrix of your data set.